# executing SQL like commands on text files

Tags: java, database, file, crud

I have to use text files as my database. The constraint is i can use only core java for all things. It is a complete CUI based MVC application with no HTML or framework stuffs. I need to store all data to files and perform update, delete operations on it. Is there a way to use java to run sql type commands to perform CRUD operations on files?

Comment: Why text files? With vanilla Java you can use e.g. an embedded JavaDB.

Comment: [This](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) will only do `select`. There is/was a CSV MIcrosoft ODBC driver that you can access with JdbcOdbcDriver (<= Java 7)

Comment: Nope. I am using ubuntu and can not create JDBC connection(part of constraint). I hope only FileReader and fileWriter are the options for me. Suggest if any better option is aviable

Comment: Based on `Is there a way to use java to run sql type commands to perform CRUD operations on files` and `i can use only core java` the answer is simply `no there isn't such thing`. If you cannot use any 3rd party library you have to code all yourself (this is possible with core Java, it's only a matter of effort/time you need to spend).